# Geopandas Spatial Join Fails - Unsupported Format String

Tags: python, pandas, spatial, geopandas

Trying to count the number of businesses around any intersection by doing a spatial join and listing every point and the polygon to which that point belongs.

I'm loading in Open Street Map road data and isolating the intersections as point data.

I'm then buffering around each intersection with a radius of 200 meters.

I have business point data that I'm loading in and trying to run the following:

```
dfsjoin = gpd.sjoin(biz_point_data, intersection_buffer, how='left', op='within')
```

Getting the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported format string passed to
>   numpy.ndarray.**format**

Both geodataframes have valid geometries, I can plot them both. And they are both in the same CRS.

Thoughts on where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Not directly an idea from that error message. Can you show the full error traceback? Or even better, can you provide a reproducible code example? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

So I've actually figured this out. The dataframe just had an index, the geometry, and some numeric data tagged to the geometry. Apparently, geopandas needs some sort of text with which to run the join, so I added a text ID before the geometry and everything worked.

Comment: Hey, I tried to add a text column, but it did not work. Maybe I'm not doing exacty what you did. Could you explain with more detail what you mean by " added a text ID before the geometry"? Thanks